# Unity3D Photon Player Controlling All Other Players

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am following Aiden is All Knowing's Multiplayer FPS tutorial and can't seem to solve this issue.

I have copied and pasted the exact code he use in the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTzR3ypM_Qc).

When I launch the game everything works fine but when the second player joins problems arise. When one player moves the other moves instead of it and when one player shoots the other the player who fired the weapon receives the damage and the second player does not have the fps cam activated!!!

I have put the character prefab in the correct place btw. AND THERE IS NO ERRORS!

Sorry if the answer is blatantly obvious or in the video, I have spent 5+ hours trying to fix this. :(

[Player Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOo2O.png)

Comment: I am happy to post more images of my inspector or more of my code if you need it! Although all of the code is shown in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed It! I had a camera enabled when it shouldn't have been so.